# Converting a list of datetime objects to strings

Tags: python, datetime

I want to convert a list of datetime objects into strings, but am confused on how to accomplish this task.

```
hm=dt.date(2013,1,2)
t=hm.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
t
```

This produces : `'01/02/2013'`

However, when I change up the variable to be a list of dates as so, it throws off an error.

```
hm=[dt.date(2013,1,1), dt.date(2013,1,2)]
t=hm.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
t
```

Error: `list indices must be integers or slices, not datetime.date`

Do I need to use some sort of `for` loop to accomplish this task?

Comment: use a list comprehension: `t_strings = [t.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for t in [dt.date(2013,1,1), dt.date(2013,1,2)]]`

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the list to convert each individual date into a `string`:

```
>>> t = [d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for d in hm]
```

Or if you want a `string` with all dates converted to a string concatenated by some other `string` (let's say `,`) you can also do as:

```
>>> s = ', '.join(t)
```

Comment: How does this look using the standard for looping procedure?

Comment: This is what is call list comprehension. You can take a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comprehensions-in-python/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve this problem with a "conventional" `for` loop you can use:

```
import datetime as dt

hm = [dt.date(2013, 1, 1), dt.date(2013, 1, 2)]
t = []

for date in hm:
    t.append(date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Otherwise the answer posted by dcg would be a cleaner and much better method.